# Cross-platform ad hosting and in-app purchasing using Xamarin

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin

I am a Windows-centric developer, currently prototyping a Windows Phone 8 app which I want to offer on iOS and Android by porting to Xamarin. The app will be ad-funded and will have an in-app purchase component (i.e. pay for an ad-free experience). I have been acquainting myself with the Microsoft features for ad hosting and in-app purchasing. Can the Microsoft ad system be used cross-platform? Can the Microsoft in-app purchase API be used in iOS and Android ports, or does in-app purchasing have to be part of the platform-specifics and use the respective stores?

Answer (score 0):

In-App purchasing is platform specific.